# Error al registrarse desde un celular en foros phpBB

Tags: php

Al querer hacer un registro de usuario desde un celular en un foro *phpBB 3.2* da error:

> El formulario enviado no era válido. Intente enviarlo de nuevo.

Ya probé con varios hospedajes, con instalaciones limpias, el estilo es el que viene por defecto, esto pasa solo desde celulares, desde una computadora funciona bien.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor revisa [qué funciones tiene el sitio para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tu pregunta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78)

Comment: @Gustavo si el phpBB lo estás implementando en tu  sitio, por favor agrega el código relevante. Si la pregunta es respecto al phpBB de un tercero, éste no sería el lugar para preguntar (en cambio, en el soporte de phpBB o quién lo haya implementado y no te dejé acceder)

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas poner el código de error que te genera. Así mismo, puede ser que el estilo o alguna extensión esté fallando. Quizás la solución es reinstalarlo, sin hacer modificaciones.